# Static in local scope

Tags: c, visual-c++, static

Just for learning purposes, I'm declaring a variable as local_persist(static) within a callback function. If I declare the variable as static directly, the address persists on every invocation and I get the correct behavior which is an alternating color. The problem arises when I use local_persist rather than static, then it doesn't persist the next time the function is called. Using VS2015 - MSVC:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define internal static;
#define global_variable static;
#define local_persist static;

INT m_ClientWidth = 1600;
INT m_ClientHeight = 900;
DWORD m_WndStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;

HWND GetMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
void Update(float dt);
void Render(float dt);

LRESULT CALLBACK MsgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT Paint;
            HDC DeviceContext = BeginPaint(hwnd, &Paint);
            int X = Paint.rcPaint.left;
            int Y = Paint.rcPaint.top;
            int Height = Paint.rcPaint.bottom - Paint.rcPaint.top;
            int Width =  Paint.rcPaint.right - Paint.rcPaint.left;
            local_persist DWORD Operation = WHITENESS;
            PatBlt(DeviceContext, X, Y, Width, Height, Operation);

            Operation = Operation == WHITENESS ? BLACKNESS : WHITENESS;
            EndPaint(hwnd, &Paint);
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }   
}

int Run()
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Update
            Update(0.0f);
            //Render
            Render(0.0f);
        }
    }

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

void Update(float dt)
{

}

void Render(float dt)
{

}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND mainWindow = GetMainWindow(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);

    if (mainWindow == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    ShowWindow(mainWindow, SW_SHOW);

    return Run();
}

HWND GetMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //WNDCLASSEX
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = MsgProc;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = "MAINWINDCLASS";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        OutputDebugString("\nFAILED TO REGISTER WINDOW CLASS\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    RECT r = { 0, 0, m_ClientWidth, m_ClientHeight };
    AdjustWindowRect(&r, m_WndStyle, FALSE);
    UINT width = r.right - r.left;
    UINT height = r.bottom - r.top;

    UINT x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2 - width / 2;
    UINT y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2 - height / 2;
    HWND m_hAppWnd = CreateWindow(wcex.lpszClassName, "Test Application", m_WndStyle, x, y, width, height, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    if (!m_hAppWnd)
    {
        OutputDebugString("\nFAILED TO CREATE WINDOW\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return m_hAppWnd;
}
```

Comment: What is `local_persist`?, it's certainly not standard c.

Comment: Just a #define ->

#define local_persist static

Comment: Then it should work properly. I don't know whether the standard allows `static` someplace else than at the beginning of a function, though...

Comment: @Dimenus Please show your full code to us, including the `local_persist` definition. Make sure you actually tested the code you show us.

Comment: Full code added in pastebin. Sorry to use another site, but formatting the entire file is ugly. Should I do something else?

As mentioned in the original question, the code works completely fine if you just sub static in for local_persist.

Comment: Um, what is the URL for the PasteBin?

Comment: Looks like @Mat edited for me and embedded the code in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Don't obfuscate standard features like `static` storage specifier. Even worse you use different `#define`s for the same keyword/feature. Any reason you want your code to become unreadable?

Comment: And site rules require all relevant code to be **in** the question. Also you shall provide a [mcve].

Comment: Don't mix declarations and statements in [tag:c], that makes variables hard to follow for humans. Instead a single point where you declare variables (*usually at the beginning of a scope*) can help human readers find the declaration quickly.

Comment: @Olaf - Understood. I wouldn't normally obfuscate standard features, but the training I'm going through does that in the case of static just because its multiple behaviors are confusing to a newbie (that's my guess anyway).

Comment: @iharob - Understood. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @Dimenus: I strongly disagree. These macros are much more confusing than just properly explaining the semantics of _storage specificers_. - As your question clearly shows. Get a better teacher. As that is likely not possible, I'd recommend to read a good C book. But get one which at least covers C99, not ol' K&R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `;` at the end of your macro definitions.

```
#define internal static;
#define global_variable static;
#define local_persist static;
```

So when you write:

```
local_persist DWORD Operation = WHITENESS;
```

it expands into:

```
static; DWORD Operation = WHITENESS;
```

The semicolon ends the statement, so it's not part of the declaration of `Operation`.

Get rid of those semicolons, it should be:

```
#define internal static
#define global_variable static
#define local_persist static
```

Then `local_persist` will act just like `static`.

Comment: Thank you! Marked as the answer.